# .Net Core 3.1 - Como usar Enum para substituir string de código

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, orientação-a-objetos

Arquivo separado:

```
 public enum LANG { NOT_SET = 0, ENGLISH = 1, PORTUGUESE = 2 }
```

Arquivo no qual quero colocar o enum que por enquanto está sendo validado com string:

```
public bool Validate(StructuralData data) {
    if ((int) (data.Language = GetLanguage()) <= 0)
        throw new Exception(
        "LANGUAGE variable not set properly, available languages:\n" + 
        "\"ENGLISH\" OR \"PORTUGUESE\"");
```

De forma resumida, quero passar o que está no enum para o que está em string.

O que eu quero é poder utilizar os Enums, de maneira que eles possam substituir o valor que está em string que seria o English or Portuguese, eu quero colocar a variável enum ali e ele me retornar do mesmo jeito em string só que, através da variável.

Comment: formate a parte do código para ser mais legível.

Comment: Você quer alterar a mensagem para usar o nome dos itens do enum ao invés das constantes "ENGLISH" e "PORTUGUESE"?

Comment: como eu disse, a validação está sendo feita por uma string, e eu quero deixá-la sendo feita apelo Enum.

Comment: @Luizeradev Não tem nenhuma validação por string no código mostrado

Comment: Está dificil entender o que você quer fazer, precisa explicar melhor sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente, para comparar o valor de um Enum você pode converter para `int` ou `string`:

`(int)LANG.ENGLISH == 1`

ou

`LANG.ENGLISH.ToString() == "ENGLISH"`

Se estiver querendo **concatenar** os valores na mensagem de `Exception` que estão em `string` você pode usar [interpolação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

`$"LANGUAGE variable not set properly, available languages:\n {LANG.ENGLISH} OR {LANG.PORTUGUESE}"`

A interpolação vai chamar o método `ToString()` disponível no seu enumerador visando formatar a `string` corretamente.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi muito bem o objetivo da sua pergunta, mas caso vc queira comparar a string com o Enum, você pode utilizar dessa maneira:

```
string teste = "NOT_SET";       
Console.Write(LANG.NOT_SET.ToString() == teste); //True
```

Caso não queira mais utilizar a string, pode usar o número do seu Enum

```
Console.Write((int) LANG.ENGLISH ==  1); //True
```